# Oracle 8i - Error signaled in parallel query server

Tags: oracle, aix

I am attempting to run a query against an Oracl 8i database instance running on Aix.  It is a simple select * against a single table.  The query runs for approximately 8 hours and then throws the following error.  Any insight on this would be appreciated.

```
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P025
ORA-01410: invalid ROWID
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple "SELECT *"? Does that mean no WHERE clause? I've seen this error when an index contains a corrupted rowid.

If you are using a where clause that causes one or more indexes to be used, try rebuilding them (if feasible).

Comment: This did have a where clause and yes I believe your comment to be correct - Oracle claims that you need to rebuild the table - i.e indexs and then flush the db cache.

Comment: Yeah @DCookie is right, this almost always means a corruption in the table somewhere, either the indexes or the data itself. If you drop all the indexes and the error still occurs, it's a restore from backup job.